# Word problem involving random variables confusion

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose a university is composed of $55\%$ female students and $45\%$ male students.  A student is selected to complete a questionnaire.  There are $25$ questions on the questionnaire administered to a male student and $30$ questions on the questionnaire administered to a female student. If $X$ denotes the number of questions answered by a randomly selected student, then compute $P(X=x)$ for every real number $x$.

First, I started by computing

$P(X=1) = (0.55)(\frac{1}{30}) + (0.45)(\frac{1}{25})$

$P(X=2) = (0.55)(\frac{2}{30}) + (0.45)(\frac{2}{25})$

.
.
.

$P(X=25) = (0.55)(\frac{25}{30}) + (0.45)(\frac{25}{25})$

.
.
.

$P(X=30) = (0.55)(\frac{30}{30})$

Then, I noticed what is the pattern, and wrote the mass function to be:

$p(x)=$
\begin{cases} 
      (0.55)(\frac{x}{30}) + (0.45)(\frac{x}{25}) & x \in \{1,2,...,25\} \\
      (0.55)(\frac{x}{30}) & x \in \{26, ..., ,30\} \\
      0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}

However, the solution at the back of the textbook was

$p(x)=$
\begin{cases} 
      0.45 & x = 25 \\
      0.55 & x = 30 \\
      0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}

How did they get this answer? Am I misinterpreting this question?

Comment: Yes you seem confused.  If the student is male they get 25 questions, if they are female they get 30 questions, how could they get any other number of questions if all the students are either male or female?  Why did you compute a probability that they get one question, for example?

Comment: Can't it be the case that for example, a male student only answers 1 question out of 25?

Comment: If that were the case, they would have had to give you some information on what the probability of that happening is.  I agree that the question is a little vague, but the lack of anything like the information needed for a different answer strongly suggests the official answer.

Comment: I see. So, in the way that this question is configured, we basically assume that each student answers all of their assigned questions and cross out the possibility that they may answer less questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you misinterpreted the question. Each student has $2$ options: to either answer the $25$-question paper (this is what $45\%$ would do), or answer the $30$-question paper (this is what $55\%$ would do). Hence if you randomly pick a student, you'll get the probabilities mentioned in the answer in your book, since each student answers either $25$ or $30$ questions, depending upon sex.